# Error Code 514 on moveItemAtURL when file name is over 100 characters long

Tags: ios, iphone, move, nsfilemanager

I am moving a file within my project and I get: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=514 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 514.)"

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:oldLocation
                                                toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newLocation]
                                                error:&error]
```

The locations I am using are valid and what is causing the error is when the file name is over 100 characters. Is there a unwritten rule about file name length?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for file names and file paths.

You can check out my answer to this question here:

[Custom URL Scheme maximum URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546582/custom-url-scheme-maximum-url-length/32215739#32215739)