# Whats the max length can iOS take for deeplink/url

Tags: ios, maxlength, deeplink

I have a long deeplink for ios, but it cut off, I did some research on PATH_MAX, looks like 1024 is max. Any way to get around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546582/custom-url-scheme-maximum-url-length?rq=1

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom URL Scheme maximum URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546582/custom-url-scheme-maximum-url-length)